# How can I optimized multiple youtube?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

My page has several youtube player, it caused the page loading slowly.
This is my code↓

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');


tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'mCx3oxXBmGA'
    });

player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  videoId: 'SpWR0sSEgMc'
});
```

the HTML↓

```
<div id="player6"></div>
```

There are 12 video in this page, how can I optimized it?

Comment: Use placeholder images that load the video when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not embed all 12 players at once. Instead present some cover image of the YouTube movie (static img) and bind `click` event on it.

When user will click specific image, remove it from the DOM and create player instead of it.